# firebase push notification onMessage payload not working in php

Tags: javascript, laravel, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to integrate firebase cloud messaging 'FCM' on my payment page. it shows numberTokensSuccess 1 but no payload. I am writing the output to console.I am not getting any error.It is not working. Please help

I'm using https://github.com/brozot/Laravel-FCM .

I have added to top of the page

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.21.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.21.1/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
<link rel="manifest" href="{{ asset('core/manifest.json') }}" />
```

my firebase.js `<script src="{{ asset('assets/js/firebase.js') }}"></script>`

```
const firebaseConfig = {
 apiKey: "XXX",
 authDomain: "XXX",
 databaseURL: "XXX",
 projectId: "XXX",
 storageBucket: "XXX",
 messagingSenderId: "XXX",
 appId: "XXX",
 measurementId: "XXX"
};


firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const messaging = firebase.messaging();
    messaging.requestPermission()
    .then(function() {
        console.log("Notification permission granted");
        return messaging.getToken();
    }).then(function(token) {
        $('#device_token').val(token);
        console.log(token);
    }).catch(function (err){
        console.log("Unable to get the permission to notify",err);
    });
    messaging.onMessage((payload) => {
        console.log(payload);
    });
```

firebase-messaging-sw.js

```
    importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.21.1/firebase-app.js");
    importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.21.1/firebase-messaging.js");

    const firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "XXX",
      authDomain: "XXX",
      databaseURL: "XXX",
      projectId: "XXX",
      storageBucket: "XXX",
      messagingSenderId: "XXX",
      appId: "XXX",
      measurementId: "XXX"
    };

      firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
      const msg = firebase.messaging()

        msg.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
          console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message',payload);
          var notificationTitle = 'Background Message Title';
          var notificationOptions = 
          {
            body: 'Background Message Body',
            icon: '/firebase-logo.png'
          }

          return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);

        });
```

Comment: Are you getting any 404 errors on the network tab?

Comment: No I am not getting any error. Page is loaded